# Calling a javascript function from other file

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript file that I'm am calling in the `head` of an HTML file, it's called `custom.js`, it defines this function:

```
var example = function(element){
  console.log(element);
};
```

Then in the actual HTML document, just before the body tag closes, I try to initialize it by calling the same function like this

```
example('.header-background');
```

I get the error example is not a function, what exactly am I doing wrong? Thank you so much for your help.

here is a bit more context

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

 // the main body of html

<script src="custom/custom.js"></script> // here is the file with the example function

example ('.header-background'); // here im calling the function
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This sounds like a scope issue. Is the first code inside a function definition?

Comment: Nothing in this question seems to refer to jQuery. It just looks like raw Javascript. There's no such thing as "a jquery file".

Comment: jQuery is just a JavaScript Library, it's not a new langauge, it's still just JavaScript.

Comment: @Barmar it's likely `'.header-background'` is meant to be a selector and it should be logging a jQuery element and not the text. ;p

Comment: yeah my bad its a .js file, and the function is wrapped in a document.ready function, should i try removing that?

Comment: But since the function can't be found, it doesn't really matter what it's supposed to be logging.

Comment: @ElatedOwl It still has nothing to do with jQuery in the example.

Comment: @Barmar I'm not saying the jQuery tag should have stayed but it still referenced jQuery (or one would assume it should)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `var example` to `window.example`. If you declare a variable with `var` inside of a function or closure it isn't globally accessible.

e.g.,

```
function foo()
{
    var test = 'hi';
}
console.log(test); // error, test isn't accessible

function foo()
{
    window.test = 'hi';
}
console.log(test); // works
```

Global variables should generally be avoided there. There's most likely a better way to do what you want to do.

Comment: i tried that but it didnt seem to solve the issue i still got the same error

Comment: Can you post a stripped down version of your HTML page in your answer then? Need a little more info to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: just added a bit more context

Comment: i had it wrapped in document.ready and that seemed to be the issue but adding window.text ended up fixing that. What are some better ways i could do this??

Comment: actually without wrapping it in document.ready i could just write it as it was before without window.test var test works just fine

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to the file where your function in the html page you are calling the function:

```
 <script type="text/JavaScript" src="youtpathtothefile/custom.js"></script>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: What does jquery have to do with this?

Answer (score -1):

Please make sure two things:

1. your javascript file is loaded after jQuery library.
2. your javascript is loaded after the every dom in the html file has finish loading.

Maybe that could help you.

Comment: There's no reference to jQuery in the question, so what does #1 have to do with it? And how does loading the DOM affect whether the function is defined?

Comment: you said "there is a jquery file"

Comment: if so pls change your post, that make everyone misunderstanding, not my fault

Comment: I didn't write the question.

Comment: But if you're an experienced JS programmer, you should be able to see that jQuery has nothing to do with it. The OP doesn't know the difference between Javascript and jQuery, but you should.

Comment: nice and great! shabi

Comment: you said jQuery file, so you should load the jquery library before the jQuery file, so that the function defined in the jquery file can be called, this is the reason

Comment: Stop saying that "I" said jQuery. The person who wrote the question said jQuery, that wasn't me. He was mistaken when he wrote that, since his question has nothing to do with jQuery, it's just about Javascript in general.